# Chrome displays "Deceptive Site Ahead" despite proper SSL certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I am hosting on DreamHost and when I visit the site in Chrome it displays a "Deceptive Site Ahead" message. The website is bicyclefilmfestival.com. I tried disabling plugins as other answers have suggested, but that didn't fix the error message.

I confirmed that I have SSL properly set up using this site https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bicyclefilmfestival.com. I am using the Really Simple SSL plugin for SSL certification. I confirmed that I don't have Mixed Content and that I am forcing HTTPS redirects.

I sent a request for review to Google, so it's possible that they just need to address the error on their end, but I wanted to see if you all had any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your site works alright. No deception alert here. Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

"Deceptive Site Ahead" is a warning that malware has been detected on your site. It has nothing to do with SSL.

Contact your web host's support department to look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Transparency Report site reports that there is an issue with some CSS on your website:

https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fbicyclefilmfestival.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemese%2Fmoesia%2Finc%2Fprettyphoto%2Fcss%2FprettyPhoto.min.css

Just because SSL is working correctly, doesn't mean that it is serving safe content. You should investigate the flagged theme to see why Google believe it to be deceptive.